# Applying for an Irish business visa in the UK with an Indian passport and UK dependent visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, ireland

I'm an Indian national and hold an Indian passport with a UK dependent visa stamped. I'm travelling to the UK at the end of this month to visit my wife. I need to travel to Ireland for work in August. Is it possible for me to apply for an Ireland business visa in the UK?